# What is the best way to handle missing indices in a python dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I am opening a CSV file with a pandas DataFrame of which the index is made of dates. I want to handle the missing time indices, what is the best way to do it?

I know about `filter()`, and `fillna()`, is there another function?

Comment: `replace` also can help with Na

Comment: Yes, there's `resample`. Or, maybe, `dropna`.

Comment: Sample data available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for reindex i.e

```
df = df.reindex(pd.date_range(df.index.min(),df.index.max(),freq='D'))
```

In case of removing nan rows then

```
df = df.dropna()
```